# Gel or AGM batteries for remote measurement stations?

Tags: batteries

I'm resupplying remote measuring stations for geophysical survey with new batteries. We have been using 100Ah Gel batteries so far, but they keep dying after around 5 years.

We usually have a 20V and 3A power supply in place that can deliver a floating charge via a charging device for the batteries.

We only need a constant, low current (but might upgrade to hardware soon that would need up to 3A constant current at 12V.)

Operating temperatures range from -10C° to +40C°.

The batteries usually are enclosed in a box that allows very little to no gas or airflow.

I have heard that AGM batteries provide longer life if they aren't deep cycled (which ours aren't - we have a constant charging voltage applied.)

Our main concern is length of life - we want to visit those stations as little as possible.

Is there any reason to prefer Gel over AGM?

Comment: 5 years sounds about right. AGM probably won't last much longer nor flooded. What life would you want?
As well, it's not a good idea to put lead-acid batteries in an enclosure without venting - explosion hazard. You can get batteries with a vent port that you can route to the outside.
You might want to consider Lithium Ferrophosphate batteries - smaller, lighter, won't outgas and might offer a longer service life.

Comment: Thanks! 10 years would be great. And yes, I have been worried about the aspect that our batteries have been sitting in enclosed boxes (they were designed before I joined..) Apparently things have been going fine, but that is not a metric to go by, of course. I'm guessing that because of the low current we draw, not too much gas is released. I'm looking at the prices of LiFePO4 batteries, maybe we can get by with lower capacity while staying inside the budget.

Comment: Remember with LFP you can actually use most of the rated capacity on a regular basis, while using "deep cycle" lead acid batteries beyond 50% discharge shortens their life a lot. And prices are falling quite fast, certainly under $100/kWh.